# How to add a link <a> to the content inside of $scope.var of AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I have got my data from my controller like below.

**controller:**

```
$http.get('json/projects.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.projects = data;
        });
```

my data in json file is something like this:

**json:**

```
{
...
projects = ['hello world', 'www.google.com', 'hello world.']
}
```

**html:**

```
<div ng-repeat='p in projects'> {{p}} </div>
```

My question is how to display 'www.google.com' as a link rather than a simple text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the liky filter from the ngSanitize module: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky

I am afraid you will have to change your `'www.google.com'` to `'http://www.google.com'`

Comment: thanks for the great reply. Is there any possibility to display 'http://www.google.com' to something else like a button and hide the raw link?